# WordPress theme meta slider plugin integration

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to customize wordpress Accesspress unicon theme, i want to integrate meta slider shortcode

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("homepage" "[metaslider id=5]");  ?>
```

in to theme, theme have only single header image instead of that i want to add slider,

Any help is appreciated , please help me

[image: code screenshot]

[theme demo link](http://accesspressthemes.com/theme-demos/?theme=unicon)